# How to calculate the gcd of two numbers via Euclidean's algorithm

Tags: c

I have written a sample program to calculate the gcd of two numbers. Here it is:

```
#include stdio.h

int main(void) {
    int m, n, rem;

    printf("Enter two numbers consecutively(with a space between them): ");
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);

    while (m) {
        n = m % n; //problem here 
        n = rem;
    }

    printf("%d is the GCD", rem);

    return 0;
}
```

I think that I am supposed to store the output of the modulo operator statement in rem but so far my program does not respond to any input given. Can somebody give me a clue.

Comment: Ugh, what did you think when posting lines of code using `<li>` tags? That *can't* be right... Fyi, you just paste your code and hit CTRL+K while your code block is selected to format it as code (by indenting it with 4 spaces). **Please fix this!** (SO users are not going to fix such a mess, they'll most likely downvote the question instead)

Answer (score 2):

> Can somebody give me a clue.

For starters you're not changing `m` inside the loop so it can't end.

Comment: For example making n the condition: m = n % m; ? or m = m % n; ?

Comment: Thank you for the link it has helped me find the solution. Here it is http://pastebin.com/A0izJirm

Answer (score 1):

> Can somebody give me a clue

`rem` is not set an initial value and you are trying to change the value of `n` twice in the loop.

Comment: What about if i use m to store the value of m % n then i store the value of m into rem and output rem after the loop terminates?

Comment: then `m` and `rem` will have the same value.

Comment: m and rem shouldn't have the same value?

Comment: what will be the value of `n`?

Comment: I should copy n into m and n into rem for the loop to continue?

Comment: n is equal to the remainder of n % m so m % n is wrong and n = rem = n. So n = m % n; n = rem = m;

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea if you wrote out how you would use the Euclidiean algorithm manually, outside the context of a computer program but using variables.  Anyway:

```
    n = m % n; //problem here 
    n = rem;
```

How will this accomplish anything?  You say "n = one thing", then "n = another", but you don't do anything with it in the meantime.